# Can I import dump on existing & running oracle database using impdp?

Tags: database, performance, oracle10g

Can I import dump on existing/running oracle database using impdp? Would that clear the existing data before importing the new data or it would be just an update?
Note: No change in schema in new dump. The dump is taken using expdp.
Database: Oracle 10g
Appreciate your response!

Muzaffar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Impdp works only on running databases. Please also define one parameter in impdp table_exists_action with values replace/append/ignore for tables whichever you prefer.

Comment: Did you find my answer useful? Please vote up if yes.